# Google AppEngine Search API distance search, accuracy is not correct

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a strange accuracy problem using Google AppEngine Search API and doing distance searches.

when running this query:

```
distance(pos, geopoint(55.7, 13.4)) < 2000
```

I get these two documents back:

```
ScoredDocument(documentId=5649050225344512_DistanceSearch_1391166416282, fields=Field(name=pos, value=GeoPoint(latitude=55.709999, longitude=13.410000), type=GEO_POINT)], rank=97326421, scores=[-1697.2195690708354]) 

ScoredDocument(documentId=6270652252160000_DistanceSearch_1391166416282, fields= Field(name=pos, value=GeoPoint(latitude=55.715000, longitude=13.419000), type=GEO_POINT)], rank=97326418, scores=[0.0])
```

If we look at the real distances from 55.7, 13.4 to the documents locations, I measure them to be

55.709999, 13.41000 to 55.7, 13.4 = 1276 meters

55.715000, 13.419000 to 55.7, 13.3 = 2049 meters

In my query I stated < 2000 meters, expecting only one answer (the 1276 meters) but I got both.

The strange thing is if I lower the distance search to 717 meter I still get both. If i then lower it to 716 meters or less, I get no answers.

What am I doing wrong? I'm running this on a production app engine instance v1.8.8, not devserver.